# Finding the interval where a solution is certain to exist for the equation $y' + (\tan t)y = \sin t$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Given the following problem:

> Determine (without solving the problem) an interval in which the solution is certain to exist for the initial value problem $y' + (\tan t)y = \sin t, \space y(2\pi) = 0$.

I was able to get the right answer, but I do lack the understanding as to why it is the right answer. I simply took $2\pi$, and added and extracted $\frac{\pi}{2}$ to get $[\frac{3\pi}{2},\frac{5\pi}{2}$]. Seeing as it is the right answer, I understand that both $\tan t$ and $y(2\pi) = 0$ are essential parts, but the text does not explain this properly.

Comment: What is $(tan t)$ ? Is it $tan(t)$ ?

Comment: The trigonometric function $\tan$ with the variable $t$. The text writes $\tan t$ and I have seen this on many other occasions.

Comment: You are right. Sorry for that stupidity ! Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Answer.** The maximum interval is
$$I=\left(\frac{3\pi}{2},\frac{5\pi}{2}\right).$$

In general, if we are given the IVP
$$
y'=p(t)y+q(t), \quad y(a)=b,
$$
then the MAXIMAL interval where the above has solution is the MAXIMAL open interval $I$, where $a\in I$, and where $p,q$ are both continuous.

In your example, the "problem" is $\tan t$ which is continuous in 
$\mathbb R\smallsetminus\{k\pi+\frac{\pi}{2}:k\in\mathbb Z\}$. BUT, let's not forget that the domain of a solution of an ODE is an INTERVAL, and not a union of them! Hence, we simply pick the largest interval containing the initial time $t=2\pi$, where $\tan t$ is continuous.